# How do you integrate PyGame and Android SDK together inside Eclipse to build an Android App running Java SDK as the main menu for PyGame?

Tags: android, python, eclipse, pygame, pydev

I am working on a project in eclipse, i have been working for the last few months in python/pygame, making pygames in the Python IDLE. I have my eclipse build setup with android sdk and pydev to run python programs (pygame) in eclipse. What I am trying to do is build an app with the android sdk that can use my pygame inside the app (put game built in pygame on android app through android sdk) that way the main menu would be coded in java with buttons, etc, then when you click the play button it goes to the pygame code. Is there anyway of doing this, you can make individual projects of the 2, and make an android app, but I want to integrate both languages features for the best performance. How am I going to do this???? I have looked on the web and I can't find anybody talking about doing this, it may be impossible, maybe not. Is it possible for this to be done for an app in eclipse????

Comment: Check ["Pygame Subset for Android"](http://pygame.renpy.org/).

Answer (score 0):

No, there's really no way of doing this. Pygame is not natively runnable on Android: you'd need to somehow find a Pygame port to Jython and then figure out how to make that work using the Android drawing primitives. Probably more work than it is worth.

Comment: i am a little confused about doing that, i have the Jython Java file but i am not experiance enough with eclipse/java to know what Android drawing primitives. You are probably right that it would be to much work, but if so could you be more descriptive. Or is there a "PyGame" for java (or similar) i know there is a 2d java thing (no idea how to set it up and what it does) how would i get that running on eclipse for an android app instead??